# i am getting different type of database related error while implementing raven db in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ravendb, mvcjqgrid

i am new to asp.net mvc just want to learn about mvcjqgrid and raven db and i am following this link example :please help me
https://github.com/robinvanderknaap/MvcJqGrid

app build successfully and did not find any error, but getting following error while executing.

Database was not shutdown cleanly. Recovery must first be run to properly complete database operations for the previous shutdown

Line 23:             // Initialize embedded ravendb data store.
Line 24:             var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { DataDirectory = "~/App_Data" };
Line 25:             documentStore.Initialize();
Line 26:
Line 27:             // Create indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recover the embedded raven database. More information how to do that: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/eKUYf2cHUkQ

I think we accidentally committed a corrupted ravendb in the repository.

Comment: thank you so much sir @robin

can you give me the instructions how to do that.